# Package for special treatment of sequences of capitals

Tags: macros, packages, package-writing

For linguistic writing, I frequently deal with input data where sequences of capitals should be typeset not as capitals, but should be treated specially, e.g. be typeset in lower case, small caps.  Ideally, I would like a package that provides a macro "morphemize" that scans through a string and applies a user-defined macro "morpheme" to any string of more than a single capital in there.  This is the idea:

```
\morphemize{ pro.3PERS.FEM be.PAST-HABIT here}
```

should evaluate to:

```
pro.3\morpheme{PERS}.\morpheme{FEM} be.\morpheme{PAST}-\morpheme{HABIT} here
```

As far as I know there's nothing exactly like this out there, and I'll need to write a macro on my own.  So, pointers to something similar would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a linguist. From what I understand only *multiple* uppercase characters (A-Z) should be handled differently. Everything else (*single* upper case characters, a-z, punctuation, etc.) should be left untouched.

The user interface below consists of the `\morphemize` and `\morpheme` commands, as requested. Additionally, I have added the `\xformupper` command, which is applied to each uppercase character in a string of uppercase characters (this allows `\lowercase` to be used while maintaining expandability).

The basic process is to first split the argument of `\morphemize` at the spaces using `\spacesplit@morphemize` and pass the chunks to `\@morphemize` for uppercase sequence identification. This is required to preserve the spaces.

In `\@morphemize`, the command `\is@upper` is used to test for uppercase. If two are found in a row, then `\@stringofuppers` is used to get the uppercase string which is passed to `\morpheme` for processing. The `\@stringoflowers` strips the uppercase string and processes the remaining content with `\@morphemize`.

The solution (`' added to demonstrate that pre and post spaces are preserved):

```
\documentclass{article}%Answer for this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298719/89497
\makeatletter
    %document-level command to apply \morpheme to strings of uppercase characters (wrapper for \@morphemize)
    \newcommand{\morphemize}[1]{\spacesplit@morphemize#1 \nil\unskip}
    %document-level command applied to strings of uppercase characters
    \newcommand{\morpheme}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    %document-level command applied to individual uppercase characters in strings up uppercase characters
    \newcommand{\xformupper}[1]{\lowercase{#1}}

    %Recursive command to split at spaces (otherwise they are lost)
    \def\spacesplit@morphemize#1 #2\nil{%
        \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%preceeding space => eval the #2
            \space%
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty=> do nothing
            \else
                \spacesplit@morphemize#2\nil%
            \fi
        \else%
            \@morphemize#1\nil%
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty...do nothing
            \else
                \space\spacesplit@morphemize#2\nil%
            \fi
        \fi}

    %Recursive command to parse a string (without spaces) based on sequences of uppercase characters
    \def\@morphemize#1#2\nil{%
        \ifnum\is@upper#1\nil=1\relax%uppercase => treat differently
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty => treat as a single captial (pass through)
                #1%
            \else%#2 is not empty => eval if next is capital
                \ifnum\is@upper#2\nil=1\relax%next char is uppercase => string of uppercases
                    \morpheme{\@stringofuppers#1#2\nil}%
                    \@stringoflowers#1#2\nil%
                \else%next char is not uppercase => pass through unchanged
                    #1\@morphemize#2\nil%
                \fi
            \fi
        \else%lowercase => pass through
            #1%
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty => nothing left to parse
            \else%#2 is not empty => more to parse
                \@morphemize#2\nil%
            \fi
        \fi}

    %Command to return 1 if the first character is uppercase, 0 if other
    \def\is@upper#1#2\nil{%
        \ifx#1A 1\else
        \ifx#1B 1\else
        \ifx#1C 1\else
        \ifx#1D 1\else
        \ifx#1E 1\else
        \ifx#1F 1\else
        \ifx#1G 1\else
        \ifx#1H 1\else
        \ifx#1I 1\else
        \ifx#1J 1\else
        \ifx#1K 1\else
        \ifx#1L 1\else
        \ifx#1M 1\else
        \ifx#1N 1\else
        \ifx#1O 1\else
        \ifx#1P 1\else
        \ifx#1Q 1\else
        \ifx#1R 1\else
        \ifx#1S 1\else
        \ifx#1T 1\else
        \ifx#1U 1\else
        \ifx#1V 1\else
        \ifx#1W 1\else
        \ifx#1X 1\else
        \ifx#1Y 1\else
        \ifx#1Z 1\else
        0%
        \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
        \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
        \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi}

    %Recursive command expanding to the string of uppercase characters at the beginning of #1#2
    \def\@stringofuppers#1#2\nil{%
        \ifnum\is@upper#1\nil=1\relax%uppercase => carry on
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty => add a nill
                \xformupper{#1}%
            \else%#2 not empty => evaluate next char
                \xformupper{#1}\@stringofuppers#2\nil%
            \fi
        \else\fi}%lowercase => do nothing

    %Recursive command expanding to the string of lowercase characters after a string of upper case characters at the beginning of #1#2
    %process the remaining contents with \@morphemize
    \def\@stringoflowers#1#2\nil{%
        \ifnum\is@upper#1\nil=1\relax%uppercase=>carry on
            \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax%#2 is empty => the whole content was all caps...return nothing
            \else%#2 not empty => evaluate next char
                \@stringoflowers#2\nil%
            \fi
        \else%lowercase =>process with \@morphemize
            \@morphemize#1#2\nil%
        \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\noindent\verb|\morphemize{ pro.3PERS.FEM be.PAST-HABIT here}|

`\morphemize{ pro.3PERS.FEM be.PAST-HABIT here}'

\noindent\verb|\morphemize{ singleCapiTaL.LETERS here}|

`\morphemize{ singleCapiTaL.LETERS here}'

\noindent\verb|\morphemize{with.A PO.ST-space }|

`\morphemize{with.A PO.ST-space }'
\end{document}
```

[image: morphemize]

I'm sure it could be tidied up a bit (`expl3` would have been a better choice in hindsight). Also, it should be expandable, pending the user-defined `\morpheme` and `\xformupper`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot.  That's exactly what I wanted -- only sequences of two or more capitals.